# Excel: Is there a way to programmatically change the background colours of individual cells in a multi column listbox control

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multi-column list box control embedded in Excel, is there a way to change the background, font, and other attributes of an individual cell (rather than changing all the text in the listbox)?

I don't mind which listbox control I use (activeX or otherwise).

I would also consider using another control that isn't tied into the excel worksheet rows and columns (i.e. I can't use a table).

Answer (score 1):

Excel's built in listbox control doesn't really have formatting options, but you can do quite a bit with the listview control.

You'll have to add a reference to Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (from VBA window go to Tools and click References, and scroll to find it). There's not an effective way to change the background color of a single cell in the listview table, but you can change the font color and make text bold in specific cells or based on criteria.

The syntax to populate the listview is a bit different than listbox, but there's quite a bit of material online for this if you think its the way to go. Also - I have only used listview in a form, but it should be possible to add this as an ActiveX control in an actual sheet.